# Random number generator generates duplicates

Tags: java, recursion, random

Framework: Java

```
public static List<Integer> buttonIdList = new ArrayList();

public void myMainMethod() {
   for(Integer i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      int randomButtonId = getUniqueIdNumber();
   }
}

private static Integer getUniqueIdNumber() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int randomButtonId = ran.nextInt(20) + 1;

        if(buttonIdList.contains(randomButtonId)) {
            getUniqueIdNumber();
        } else {
            buttonIdList.add(randomButtonId);
        }

        return randomButtonId;
    }
```

When the code encounters a duplicate, it calls itself (recursively) and in the second try if the number is unique the return statement returns it to the myMainMethod or to getUniqueIdNUmber?

Where should the return statement be placed?

Comment: You should consider generating a collection with the numbers 1 through 20 and shuffle that, if your requirement is unique numbers.

Comment: @Henrik yes I saw that option in few of the stackoverflow questions too. but i wanted to see where i was going wrong with my own code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return the result of the recursive call:

```
private static Integer getUniqueIdNumber() {
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randomButtonId = ran.nextInt(20) + 1;

    if(buttonIdList.contains(randomButtonId)) {
        return getUniqueIdNumber();
    } else {
        buttonIdList.add(randomButtonId);
    }

    return randomButtonId;
}
```

P.S., it would be better to make `Random ran` a `static` variable instead of creating a new `Random` instance in each recursive call.

```
private static Random ran = new Random();
private static Integer getUniqueIdNumber() {
    int randomButtonId = ran.nextInt(20) + 1;
    if(buttonIdList.contains(randomButtonId)) {
        return getUniqueIdNumber();
    } else {
        buttonIdList.add(randomButtonId);
        return randomButtonId;
    }
}
```

And you might consider changing `buttonIdList` to a `HashSet` (or `LinkedHashSet` if you care about insertion order) in order to make the search for existing number more efficient.